# tensorflow-gpu install error like this..T.T python:3.10 tensorflow: 2.11.0 CUDA 10.1 cuDNN 8.0.3

Tags: tensorflow

C:\Users\CITADEL>pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python_version>"3.7" in c:\users\citadel\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.0.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
Building wheel for tensorflow-gpu (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [18 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\CITADEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3o7_0drd\tensorflow-gpu_b2c72ac2351448d18a87a109721775f4\setup.py", line 37, in 
raise Exception(TF_REMOVAL_WARNING)
Exception:

```
  =========================================================
  The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!

  Please install "tensorflow" instead.

  Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
  since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
  information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
  =========================================================


  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensorflow-gpu
Running setup.py clean for tensorflow-gpu
Failed to build tensorflow-gpu
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
Running setup.py install for tensorflow-gpu ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for tensorflow-gpu did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [18 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\CITADEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3o7_0drd\tensorflow-gpu_b2c72ac2351448d18a87a109721775f4\setup.py", line 37, in 
raise Exception(TF_REMOVAL_WARNING)
Exception:

```
  =========================================================
  The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!

  Please install "tensorflow" instead.

  Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
  since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
  information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
  =========================================================


  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> tensorflow-gpu

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do, literally in plain English.

Answer (score 11):

`tensorflow-gpu` and `tensorflow` are the same package since the release of version 2.1. Installing `tensorflow` alone will enable GPU acceleration.
You can refer to the this [link](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/) it has more details.