# Tensorflow 2.0 is not detecting my GPU and pip install tensorflow-gpu won't work (legacy-install-failure)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

My GPU is not getting detected by Tensorflow. I installed the package using

`pip3 install tensorflow`

and wrote this script:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)  # 2.13.0-rc2
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) # []
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda)  # <function is_built_with_cuda at 0x169361d00>
print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())  # (blank output)
print(tf.config.get_visible_devices())  # [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

So I looked for some solution on stackoverflow and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956619/tensorflow-2-0-list-physical-devices-doesnt-detect-my-gpu). The accepted answer suggests to run

`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`

But this won't work since I am getting:

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting python_version>"3.7"
  Downloading python_version-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
  Building wheel for tensorflow-gpu (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/gh/hgbtzhqd5xv5rwqj0snp33qm0000gn/T/pip-install-4nvf8ykd/tensorflow-gpu_cdf0b518f52f411492c5f1bc9550ef25/setup.py", line 37, in <module>
          raise Exception(TF_REMOVAL_WARNING)
      Exception:
      
      =========================================================
      The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!
      
      Please install "tensorflow" instead.
      
      Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
      since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
      information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
      =========================================================
      
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensorflow-gpu
  Running setup.py clean for tensorflow-gpu
Failed to build tensorflow-gpu
Installing collected packages: python_version, tensorflow-gpu
  Running setup.py install for tensorflow-gpu ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for tensorflow-gpu did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/gh/hgbtzhqd5xv5rwqj0snp33qm0000gn/T/pip-install-4nvf8ykd/tensorflow-gpu_cdf0b518f52f411492c5f1bc9550ef25/setup.py", line 37, in <module>
          raise Exception(TF_REMOVAL_WARNING)
      Exception:
      
      =========================================================
      The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!
      
      Please install "tensorflow" instead.
      
      Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
      since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
      information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
      =========================================================
      
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> tensorflow-gpu

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Since it seems that

> The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370648/tensorflow-gpu-install-error-like-this-t-t-python3-10-tensorflow-2-11-0-cuda) suggests to refer to [this link](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/): *tensorflow-gpu has been removed. Please install tensorflow instead. The tensorflow package supports GPU accelerated operations via Nvidia CUDA*. But even though I install tensorflow using `pip3 install tensorflow` (as suggested and as I already did), my GPU won't be detected.

If you need further information this is my computer:

```
MacBook Air 2020
Chip: Apple M1
RAM: 16 GB
macOS: 13.4.1
GPU: Apple M1, integrated, 8 cores, metal supports: metal 3
```

And I am using:

```
Interpreter: Python 3.11
IDE: PyCharm 2022.3.3 (Professional Edition)
Virtual Environment: venv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran

```
pip3 install tensorflow-macos
pip3 install tensorflow-metal
```

And now it seems to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)  # 2.13.0-rc2
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) # [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda)  # <function is_built_with_cuda at 0x169361d00>
print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())  # /device:GPU:0
print(tf.config.get_visible_devices())  # [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```